# SQLite in QT: Should I close database after running each query or not? What is the implication

Tags: database, qt, sqlite

I want to understand if I should close database after running each query or not? What is the implication.

Here is some metacode:

```
{
if (m_databaseProvider.openDatabase()) {
    QSqlQuery query(m_databaseProvider.database());
    query.prepare(SQL_SELECT_LOCATIONS);
    query.exec();

    // iterate the result and return list
    while (query.next()) {
           .....
    }
  m_databaseProvider.closeDatabase();
} else {....}
```

}

Is there any drawbacks to this approach?

What is the recmended best practive for QT Application on Android for example?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Closing the database throws away its page cache, and requires that the database structure is re-read when you reopen it for the next query.

In practice, it is unlikely that you notice any difference unless you do many small queries, or are on a small device with a weak CPU or small memory.